# How can I set MKMapView's region span dynamically so that it doesn't "snap" back to the initial Region upon redrawing the map?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, zooming, region

I am working with a MKMapview and I am having a problem with the zoom level and the region span.

It would seem when the MKMapView is refreshed it resets the region to the values that have been hardcoded when I initially installed them. I am keeping track of the user's location and with any changes in the location of the phone the map should update via the CLLocationManagerDelegate and the delegate method listed below.

Currently I have this in the locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:

```
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta =  0.8;  
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.8;     
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = newLocation.coordinate;
    region.span = span;
    [self.MyMapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
```

I have also tried putting similar code in the viewDidLoad: to no avail. My thinking is that I could somehow set the region dynamically in the

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

delegate method I could sidestep this issue entirely but I am not *exactly* sure how I should do that.

Ultimately I'd just like to have the map stop "snapping" back to the above span. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the map view "refreshed"?

Comment: Good eye Anna! I am a bit new to both iphone dev and stack overflow, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: So in viewDidLoad you set the map region (center and span).  In didUpdateToLocation, do you update the map region or just the center?  Are you trying to follow the user's location?

Comment: I basically took the exact code as above(MKcoordspan, region, etc) and have tried it in the viewDidLoad and the didUpdateLocation. Currently the code is actually in didUpdateLocation because the viewDidLoad causes a bug or two. Let me update this to show that, sorry for all the confusion I'll get the hang of this eventually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to keep the map centered on the user's current location, first decide whether you want to use:

- the map view's `userLocation` property and the map view's delegate method `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:`, or
- the `CLLocationManager` and its delegate method `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`

With either one, in `viewDidLoad`, you should just set the map view's initial region including center (using some default coordinate) and span.  The user's location will be unlikely to be available immediately in viewDidLoad as it can take a few seconds to acquire.

Trying to use `userLocation` before its set may cause an exception when setting the region with that value.

If using the map view's `userLocation`, then:

- in viewDidLoad or IB, set `mapView.showsUserLocation` to `YES`
- in the `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` method, do `mapView.centerCoordinate = userLocation.location.coordinate;` (or use `setCenterCoordinate:animated:`)
- recommend also implementing `mapView:didFailToLocateUserWithError:` to handle or at least become aware of failures

If using the `CLLocationManager`, then:

- in viewDidLoad, do `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];`
- in the `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` method, do `mapView.centerCoordinate = newLocation.coordinate;` (or use the animated method)
- recommend also implementing `locationManager:didFailWithError:` to handle or at least become aware of failures

Comment: I want the user to be able to zoom in and remain at that zoom level despite what updating occurs. I have done these suggestions and the problem persists. I know it is hard to help me without full access to the code so if it isn't possible then I will just have to keep truckin. Thanks for the attempt though =)

Comment: Sure.  But there must be some other method updating the map's region or span besides didUpdateToLocation.  The map view won't do it automatically.  Try searching the project for all calls that modify the map view.

Comment: I believe I discovered the issue. The mapview's distanceFilter was set to kCLDistanceFilterNone. I didn't think that would be it but the bug is either resolved or "hidden" regardless can I somehow give you credit for your help even if it doesn't explicitly answer the question?

Comment: The distanceFilter is on the CLLocationManager not the map view so I'm not sure how that would have an effect.  You are welcome to post an answer to your question yourself with your solution (I think you can accept it in 2 days).  Anyway, on SO, giving credit is done by upvoting (up arrow on top-left of answer) or accepting an answer (checkmark on top-left of answer).  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82286/how-do-i-give-someone-reputation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by creating a `UIViewController` subclass to hold the `MKMapView` instance. I restore the mapView's span in `loadView`, and then call `[mapView setUserTrackingMode:...]` in the VC's `viewWillAppear` method.

I saw the behavior the OP described in a previous implementation, where I created a VC and a `MKMapView' instance on the fly and then pushed it onto my navigation controller. I was never able to both set the span and set user tracking to follow the user without the span getting lost. I did some debugging and even saw that the original span values were being discarded when the view displayed, so I think it had something to do with setting span or setting the user tracking mode without the view having been displayed. At any rate, organizing the code as above solved the problem.

Here are the relevant bits:

```
// ===== mainVC.h =====
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface MapVC : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
@end

// ===== mainVC.m =====   
static MapVC *map = nil;

- (void)mapAction {
    UINavigationController *nav = [self navigationController];

    // map VC is a singleton
    if (!map) map = [[MapVC alloc] init];

    [nav pushViewController:map animated:TRUE];
}


// ===== MapVC.m =====
- (void)loadView {
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [mapView setDelegate:self];
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinatSpanMake(storedLatitudeDelta, storedLongitudeDelta);
    [mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(storedCenter, span)];
    [self setView:mapView];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:TRUE];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    MKCoordinateSpan mySpan = [mapView region].span;
    storedLatitudeDelta = mySpan.latitudeDelta;
    storedLongitudeDelta = mySpan.longitudeDelta;
}
```

I pruned that out of a bigger project, so let me know if you see any typos, but that's the gist of it.